# Migrated to new server, DNS setup >48 hrs, some MySQL inserts from domain still show up on old server

Tags: domain-name-system, mysql, migration, dedicated-server, reverse-dns

Title says it all - I've migrated to a new dedicated server at a different IP..  It's been more than 48 hours since DNS was setup. Some MySQL inserts (standard php variables invoke mysql) from at least one domain this server hosts still show up on the old server, rather than the new. What's happening?

Here's one domain to check - http://inacentaur.com

Answer (score 0):

While most DNS servers observe cache settings, some providers set a minimum TTL to cut down on the load of having to verify domain names.  At one point, AOL.com used to set a minimum TTL of 7 days.

After 48 hours, depending on the TTL you set on your domain (or your host set), you should see about 95% of your traffic moved over.

If possible, allow remote mysql connections and have your old server connect via TCP to your new server to get any transaction.  The latency shouldn't be too bad and since it is only the stragglers, you shouldn't see too much effect, and won't lose any data.

Comment: Big prob is that the old server (from a different provider) has its term ending tonight, so will be taken off anytime now..

Comment: With the economy the way it is, it is difficult to say whether a hosting company will take a server offline the instant it is available.  Many will leave it running until they get to it or need to allocate it to another client.  However, in that situation, there really isn't much else you can do other than hope.

Comment: Unfortunately, one of the big reasons why I had to move was because my old provider was getting too promiscuous in hunting down new customers, such that they started to totally ignore their old customers (folks who had been with them for ten years) in hopes of impressing new customers. In any case, it looks like they took down my old server on the hour.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of days before migraitsey needed to reduce the TTL to 15 days.
Before the migration, make proxy requests to the old server to new server. And then edit the DNS.